# Linker error compiling keyczar program

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, static-libraries

I am using `g++ -lkeyczar -lcrypto -o basic_encrypt -Wall -O2 base_encrypt.cpp` to compile the following code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <keyczar/keyczar.h>

void EncryptAndDecrypt(const std::string& location) {
  keyczar::Keyczar* crypter = keyczar::Crypter::Read(location);
  if (!crypter)
    return;

  std::string input = "Secret message";
  std::string ciphertext;
  std::cout << "Plaintext: " << input << std::endl;

  bool result = crypter->Encrypt(input, &ciphertext);
  if (result) {
    std::cout << "Ciphertext (Base64w): " << ciphertext << std::endl;
    std::string decrypted_input;
    bool result = crypter->Decrypt(ciphertext, &decrypted_input);
    if (result)
      assert(input == decrypted_input);
  }
  delete crypter;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    std::cout << "An absolute key set location must be provided as argument"
              << std::endl;
    return 1;  // error
  }

  // The first argument must represent the keyset's location
  const std::string location(argv[1]);

  EncryptAndDecrypt(location);
  return 0;
}
```

Which is a tutorial taken from [here](http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/wiki/CppTutorial)

However, I am running into the following error:

```
/tmp/ccNlack3.o: In function `EncryptAndDecrypt(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
base_encrypt.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `keyczar::Crypter::Read(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am unable to solve this since I know that I am already giving the library flags while compiling. Why is it still unable to link correctly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the library flags at the end of the command line:

```
g++ -o basic_encrypt -Wall -O2 base_encrypt.cpp -lkeyczar -lcrypto
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem, but now I have a new one: `./basic_encrypt: error while loading shared libraries: libkeyczar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` 
I know that the installation has not placed the `libkeyczar.so` file in the usual /usr/lib folder, but rather in another location (inside the same source folder ..) But anyways, what must I do now so that g++ can find the `libkeyczar.so` ? I know where it is stored. How do I tell G++ its path ?

Comment: ok, I solved the issue by ` LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/r/l33t/Security_Model/keyczar-cpp/src/scons-out/opt-linux/lib ./basic_encrypt`